# How do I save CSV file as zip on s3 bucket using R?

Tags: r

I read few files from s3 and do some manipulation on those files .Now I want to save those CSV file as zip on s3 using R ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the csv as gz file using write_csv and then push to s3 using boto or AWS Cli

```
readr::write_csv(df, gzfile('sample.csv.gz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @sonny you can save zip file locally, by using any below function-

```
readr::write_tsv(df, file.path(getwd(), "mtcars.tsv.gz"))
```

OR

```
readr::write_csv(mtcars, file.path(dir, "mtcars.csv.gz"))
```

And then use below code to push to S3-

```
system(paste0("aws s3 cp ",file_path, " ", s3_path))
```

**Note- `file_path` should include complete file location with file name.